# Abstract a class away from PHP script?

Tags: php

Just wondering if there is anyway to have PHP just run a certain class given the name of the file (controller.php)?

I don't want to require, include or see any signs of it in the controller.php. I just want it to be there.

EDIT: Ok. What I mean by run is in some file hidden away from me I say something like... $class = new Class(); This way I can use $class in my controller.php

ALSO: I'm running PHP 5.3 - So I have namespaces and whatnot.

Anyway of doing this??

Thanks!
Matt Mueller

Comment: What do you mean "run a class"? Classes aren't something you run. What is the "it" you don't want to see in controller.php?

Comment: Ah, you want to automatically create an instance of the class defined in controller.php, but you don't want to do it in controller.php. There's always the singleton pattern, but only if it makes sense to have a single instance of the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to take a big guess at what you really mean. I think you simply want to separate your class PHP file away from your main file without making any obvious includes.

If so, you might want to use the [__autoload()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) function:

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 
?>
```

This will notice that MyClass1 and MyClass2 haven't yet been defined and will call the autoload function with their class names as the parameter. So then MyClass1.php and MyClass2.php will be require_once'd.

Comment: Great! Where would I put this though? Putting __autoload at the top of each file looks ugly!

Comment: Well you either do that or you put it in a separate file and include that file at the top of each of your other files. If you have lots of functions that should be available all over your site, you'll want a file like this anyway. Many PHP frameworks run through a single page anyway where everything is dynamically included depending on input variables, so the __autoload() function would only have to be defined once. You just have to decide which of your options is the least ugly.

Answer (score 3):

You can [autoload the Class file](http://php.net/autoload), you will still have to instantiate the Class by hand at some point. Or you will have to include a script that instantiates it for you. Or you re-architect your application so your actual script is included by another script, which pre-instantiates the Class for you.

In short: including the file can be automated, instantiating the Class not so much.